# warning curl_close()

Tags: php, curl, libcurl

I am getting `Warning: curl_close(): supplied argument is not a valid cURL handle resource in \path\ on line 123`

In the line the following code is present.

```
public function stopPlugin($graceful=false)
    {
    if ($this->settings['transport']=='curl')
        curl_close($this->curl);
    if (!$graceful) if (file_exists($this->cookie)) unlink($this->cookie);
    }
```

I got this error while using Open Inviter script Please help me to how to fix this error.

Comment: the error is with the instantiation of the curl object, find out where `$this->curl` is set

Answer (score 1):

`$this->curl` is empty or not a valid json resource :)

try

```
var_dump($this->curl);
```

to get your resources

Comment: Do you mean `curl_close(var_dump($this->curl););` or just `var_dump($this->curl);` instead of `curl_close($this->curl);`

Comment: Can you please write the syntax for me. I am totally a newbie to cURL.

Comment: var_dump($this->curl); curl_close($this->curl);  ......... var_dump just gives you more info about your $this->curl variable

Comment: I used in the below manner but it didn't work for me dude ` public function stopPlugin($graceful=false)
  {
  if ($this->settings['transport']=='curl')
   var_dump($this->curl); curl_close($this->curl);
   
  if (!$graceful) if (file_exists($this->cookie)) unlink($this->cookie);
  }`

Comment: I used in the below manner but it didn't work for me dude. ' public function stopPlugin($graceful=false)
  {
  if ($this->settings['transport']=='curl')
   var_dump($this->curl); curl_close($this->curl);
   
  if (!$graceful) if (file_exists($this->cookie)) unlink($this->cookie);
  }'

Comment: it should show you just more info about that variable, not to save your problem

Comment: @genesis let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2192/discussion-between-meutex-and-genesis)

Comment: Well. Its just closing of cURL na. I will better ignore it rather than wasting my time.